# Polygon clipping between Convex and convex or convex and concave polygon

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, polygon, clipping

Im trying to implement a polygon clipper/grower in unity. I basically have 2 Polygons, 1 that i want to clip(it is always convex), and the other i want to clip with(sometimes convex sometimes concave). It must work in 3D.

I have an idea and it goes something like this:

I know the edges and vertices of the convex polygon and i know the edges and vertices of the convex/concave object.

1) Find all the edges and vertices of the convex polygon that are inside the convex/concave polygon.

2) Find all the edges and vertices of the concave/convex polygon inside the convex polygon

3) Find the intersecting edges between convex and concave/convex polygons.

4) Calculate intersection points

5) using intersection points and convex/concave polygon vertices and edges inside convex object recreate the convex object into whatever comes out of it

6) Using the same points extend the convex/concave polygon. Disregard vertices and edges that are inside convex/concave polygon.

But the issue i have is that i dont know how to do the initial 3 steps. I will probably have some overlaying quadtree(octtree in 3D), maybe i can use that.

Any suggestion, ideas, mistakes i made?

Edit

After alot of thought i can see that i can simplify what needs to be done.

There are 3 Cases: 1) Convex is completly inside convex/concave
2) Convex intersects with convex/concave
3) No intersection

So for my purposes i only need Union and subtraction. First i do the union of 2 shapes. And then from the first shape i subtract the second shape. And then i get the part that i need. Subtraction is rather simple. I just need to find all the vertices that arent in both of the shapes. And these vertices define the part that i need.

I looked into Constructive Solid Geometry but all i could find was that what you can do with it, but not how to implement it. Can someone point me to some page or give a quick recap on how to do CSG UNION operation ?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you look into the `polygon` package by Lucanus Simonson (around 2011, I think).  His mathematical foundation work is both straightforward (once you see it) and groundbreaking.  `polygon` is now part of the BOOST C++ libraries, which makes the implementation particularly good for portation to C#.

Comment: @Prune The libary seems great. But I need a more general algorithm that would work both in 3D and 2D.

Comment: If 3D is a *requirement*, then please edit the question to reflect that.  Don't just grab the `polygon` package: also read the underlying papers for the calculus that Luke developed.  From what I recall, it can be generalized to any number of dimensions, although the performance will no longer be linear.

Comment: I read the paper. But i dont understand where does he get those -1,0,+1 on the vertices. And also  i dont understand how does he choose the numbers to do XOR on.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  I don't have time this quarter to spin up on the math again (I was a tertiary reviewer of the presentation).  I'm hopeful that someone current in BOOST might be able to help with this aspect.